# Laravel nova action download a file causes : Failed - no file

Tags: php, laravel, action, laravel-nova

I want to create a file and download it during a Laravel Action.

I use the following code:

```
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'example');
        $url = Storage::disk('local')->url('file.txt');
        return Action::download($url, 'file.txt');
    }
```

This causes the following error :

`Failed - no file`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is path issue, This may helps : return Action::download(storage_path('app/public/' . $filename));

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Ghanshyam, This does however not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where that error message comes from, but it may be the following problem. Calling `return Action::download($url, 'file.txt')` laravel nova will instruct the browser to download the file at the given url. As mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls) this url will (depending on your config) probably be the relative url `/storage/file.txt`. So the browser will try to download `http(s)://domain/storage/file.txt` which might not be there. The docs mentioned above hold a solution for that.

If you wouldn't even want to create a file which would maybe need cleanup and protection if the data is sensitive, you could as well point the url to a route and do processing in a controller.